# How to separate event code behind to seperate class?

Tags: c#, wpf

So far i separated action with Command Binding. but i need to implent many thing to work same as built-in event. ex, OnClick, OnChange and so on. the MVVM pattern only means is no code behind in ViewModel class. all thing like Component. instead make all thing from scratch. why not just make Event in ViewModel implementation like component. so just attacch and detach that event collection class. is there new way to do this? so far i can think is encapsulate control with event and inhrited to viewmodel class.

```
public class Utility
{
 public static string Manipulation(string search)
 {
   return search + "Reesult";
 }
}

public class CustomWindow : Window
{
  protected virtual void SearchBtn(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    MessageBox.Show( Utility.Manipulation(search.Text) );
  }
}

public partial WindowViewModel : CustomWindow
{
    public WindowViewModel
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

<TextBox x:Name="search" />
<Button Click="SearchBtn"> Search </Button>
```

Comment: Commands can be generic. Behaviors are another way to encapsulate code. You can apply both using styles. You should be more specific in your question. At the moment it's unclear why a command is not the answer.

Comment: You can use Behaviours to execute Commands based on Events. Is that what you are trying to achieve? Your question is a bit unclear.

Comment: @jeanluc162 i edit the example code, i can achieve seperation with language encapsulation. i want to know WPF ways. is there like something method or something that attach collection event from class to viewmodel. and i dont know why command binding still usefull. it just make so many boiler plate code into project.

Comment: i checked almost common behaviour already exist in event. the disadvantage of this encapsulation. it tight to control object. but still follow mvvm pattern.

Comment: Please clarify your problem. It's difficult to understand. Why does your view model extend CustomWindow? In terms of MVVM your view model must not be a control as controls are components of the view. If your question is how to reuse code of a control then creating a base class is a valid solution. MVVM does never state that code-behind is not allowd. This doesn't make much sense as MVVM is concerned with application level design and not class level design. If you check the WPF library you will find many controls that are based on extending a baseclass. For example ListBox extends ItemsControl.

Comment: @BionicCode ViewModel class is not code behind of gui xaml? ex, `MainWindow.cs, MainWindow.xaml.cs`. MainWindow.cs is ViewModel. i read alot mvvm is about design to seperate designer with logic. as long follow that. it doesn't matter how to manipulate in behind. so i think i can achieve it with just encapsulate control with event that needed. than inherit to viewmodel class. than about manipulation that event handle in separate classs again like utility. i edit the example utitility code.

Comment: @BionicCode i just dont want to reinvent all event behaviour that already exist. how attach and detach event in seperation class?

Comment: It looks like you are making your life hard because you completely misunderstood the concept of MVVM. It's about decoupling  business logic aka application logic from the UI. View Model is the extra layer between UI and application logic to prevent the UI from bleeding into the actual application. A *xaml.cs* file is simple a partial class and the code-behind (C#) file of the XAML code file of a control. XAML is theprimary language when it comes to UI authoring. But it is limited (it's a markup language), so you can add C# code to support your XAML.

Comment: [Part 5. From Data Bindings to MVVM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm#a-simple-viewmodel) (it's about Xamarin but the concept is the same. Xamarin is very similar to WPF), [Patterns - WPF Apps With The Model-View-ViewModel Design Pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern)

Comment: Be very careful when looking up random MVVM tutorials on the internet. Many are not quite accurate or even plain wrong.